# Can Non-Robot Minions be Reclaimed via Microbot Reclaimer?

Tags: smash-up

When a **Microbot Alpha** has been played, it gives an ongoing action of

> [...] All of your minions are considered Microbots.

*Does this include minions in your discard pile?*

The question came up in a game where a subsequent **Microbot Reclaimer** was played, which states:

> [...] Shuffle any number of Microbots from your discard pile into your deck.

Does this combination allow for reclaiming minions "considered" as Microbots, even when they are in the discard pile as well as from another faction?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that when a Microbot Alpha is in play, it "gains +1 power for each of your other Microbots."

I wouldn't consider counting discarded Microbots here, so I'm leaning that other minions in the discard wouldn't be considered Microbots any longer.

Answer (score 2):

As included in the [Pretty Pretty Smash Up rules](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf), page 10:

> "A minion" or "minions" means any minions in play unless stated otherwise.

This means that minions in your discard pile are not affected by an action that states "minions".

So no, minions in your discard pile are not classed as Microbots due to the Alpha as they are not in play.

Comment: Good catch! I've come across this situation a number of times and I don't think I've ever been pointed to the rules for it, but knowing that's there makes it clear.